# Is there some way to extend the created model fields another model in django?

Tags: django, django-models

Say, I want to create two models, out of which for the all the fields for the second model will remain same as the first model, with addition of a few more fields. Is there a good way to achieve this?

One way is to use abstract class as the first model, but this will mean i wont be able to add instances of the first model. You can find examples in the code below:

Say we have two models as:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    m1field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255,required=True)
    m1field2 = models.CharField(...)
    m1field3 = models.CharField(...)
    ...
    m1field8 = models.CharField(...)
```

```
class Model2(models.Model):
    m1field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255,required=True)
    ...
    m1field8 = models.CharField(...)
    m2field1 = models.CharField(...)
    ...
    m2field5 = models.CharField(...)
```

As you can see I have to redefine the m1field1 - m1field8 again in the Model2, if I have to reuse it.
Is there some way, to not repeat it again.
I tried the following:

```
class Model2(Model1):

    m2field1 = models.CharField(...)
    ...
    m2field5 = models.CharField(...)
```

But, this didnt work as in the hindsight, it creates a OneToOneField of Model2 to Model1, which obviously wont work, as I will have to first create a Model1 with the given fields and then Model2 with the fields and then link it to Model1.

One probable solution is to use abstract model, with the common fields. But is there some other method to achieve the same results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create mixin for common fields like this.

```
class CommonFieldsMixin(models.Model):
    m1field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255,required=True)
    m1field2 = models.CharField(...)
    m1field3 = models.CharField(...)
    ...
    m1field8 = models.CharField(...)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Use this mixin in both models.

```
class Model1(CommonFieldsMixin, models.Model):
    pass

class Model2(CommonFieldsMixin, models.Model):
    m2field1 = models.CharField(...)
    m2field5 = models.CharField(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
class ModelBase(models.Model):
    # declare a base abstract class 
    m1field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255,required=True)
    m1field2 = models.CharField(...)
    m1field3 = models.CharField(...)
    ...
    m1field8 = models.CharField(...)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Model1(ModelBase):
     # subclass from abstract class 
     pass

class Model2(ModelBase):
    # subclass from abstract class 
    m2field1 = models.CharField(...)
    ...
    m2field5 = models.CharField(...)
```

Comment: Tried this. Getting the error. You are trying to add non-nullable field 'modelbase_ptr' to the model, and asking for a default. But, for a base model this issue should not come, right?